# At what point will the turret benefit from Molten Core

Tags: overwatch

It might be just me imagining things, but if I replace my freshly destroyed turret and hit Q, the turret remains at Level 1. **At what point of the life-cycle of the turret will it upgrade to level 3 ?**
Is it when it's just placed, or when it's just placed but had the time to fully deploy, or maybe it needs to be level 3 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Turret needs to be upgraded to level 2 before it will turn into a level 3 turret. As soon as it hits level 2 it instantly upgrades to level 3 if Molten Core is active.

Comment: May also be worth noting that while in Molten Core you can upgrade the turret to level 2 faster.

Comment: @Mayshar are you sure about that? As far as I can remember, the one time I had to do this, it still took the standard 6 swings to upgrade. Is Torbojrn's melee rate faster in Molten Core mode?

Comment: yes, all of his attacks are faster in molten core, including swinging his hammer. I still think it takes 6, but he gets those 6 done much faster.

Comment: Isn't it 5 swings to upgrade turret to lvl 2 ?

Comment: It is 5 swings, not 6. It looks like 6 beacuse people typically hit it while still in the build animation. If you look at the progress circle around the level of the turret in the lower left corner, you can see 5 distinct progress updates, not 6.

Comment: how many seconds does it take to upgrade turret?